# video.audioTracks property doesn't work in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, video, puppeteer, video-capture

I use Puppeteer to launch a browser page, just like as follows:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
      headless: true,
      devtools: true,
      args: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-web-security',
          '--allow-file-access-from-files',
          '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
          '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
          '--disable-gpu'
    ]
});
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(`http://localhost:3001/hello.html`);
```

the `hello.html` page works great, but when I create a `Video` element and read the [`audioTracks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) property, it returns **undefined**.

However, if I use the same code in Google Chrome directly, which is not launched by Puppeteer, `video.audioTracks` returns correctly.

```js
const video = document.createElement('video')
console.log('tracks:', video.audioTracks) // should be tracks: AudioTrackList, but undefined in Puppeteer
```

It just makes me confused..Hope someone can explain this odd behavior.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you show a minimal version of the website's code that creates a Video element and reads the audioTracks property? Are you actually putting this element into the DOM at some point? How are you selecting it in Puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

I just accidently found that I have enable `experimental-web-platform-features` flag in my Goole Chrome , so `GOOGLE CHROME` works well.. But when I use puppeteer to launch a page , I should enable it as well..

`audioTracks` is not enabled by default, please use `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag to enable it..

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
      headless: true,
      devtools: true,
      args: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-web-security',
          '--allow-file-access-from-files',
          '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
          '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--enable-experimental-web-platform-features', // add here
    ]
});
```